# Javascript drag and drop with one elemant

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently learning JavaScript and have created code allowing a user to drag and drop an item. However, this code requires there to be two objects in the list of objects when I want there only to be one. I believe the issue is due to using for loops which start from 0 and require the length of the list of items to be greater than 0. But due to lists starting from a 0 index, this doesn't happen. My code is:

```
const list_items = document.querySelectorAll('.list-item');
const lists = document.querySelectorAll('.list');

let draggedItem = null;

for (let i = 0; i < list_items.length; i++) {
const item = list_items[i];

item.addEventListener('dragstart', function () {
    draggedItem = item;
    setTimeout(function () {
        item.style.display = 'none';
    }, 0)
});

item.addEventListener('dragend', function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        draggedItem.style.display = 'block';
        draggedItem = null;
    }, 0);
})

for (let j = 0; j < lists.length; j ++) {
    const list = lists[j];

    list.addEventListener('dragover', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    list.addEventListener('dragenter', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });


    list.addEventListener('drop', function (e) {
        console.log('drop');
        this.append(draggedItem);
    });
   }
}
```

Comment: Why is `list_items` defined as `var` and `lists` defined as `const`?

Comment: That was for my own expermentation where I tried to add one to list items.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, so it might not work: have you tried changing your for loops from

```
(let j = 0; j < lists.length; j ++)
```

to

```
(let j = 0; j <= lists.length; j ++)
```

`<=` in JS is less than or equal to

Comment: and do the same to the 1st for loop

Comment: That will cause an error when trying to access `lists[j]`

Comment: The length usually is larger than the index for index to start at 0 and length to start at 1. So the `<` is correct.

Comment: I just tried this and it returns a type errors with list.